# Building blocks not working via panini on Foundation 6 Zurb stack

Tags: components, zurb-foundation

On new install of Foundation 6 Zurb stack, installing building block sticky-shrinknav and injecting it into index.html template using {{> sticky-shrinknav}} shows the component on the page but scrolling the page does not produce the expected result.

Tried installing Zurb stack multiple times in different locations. Same results are produced.

This is the index.html template:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Veridata</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{root}}assets/css/app.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    {{> sticky-shrinknav}}
    {{!-- Pages you create in the src/pages/ folder are inserted here when the flattened page is created. --}}
    {{> body}}

    <script src="{{root}}assets/js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My app.scss file contains:

```
@import 'components/building-blocks/sticky-shrinknav';
```

and my config.yml contains:

```
# Paths to JavaScript entry points for webpack to bundle modules
entries:
    - "src/assets/js/building-blocks/sticky-shrinknav.js"
    - "src/assets/js/app.js"
```

Expecting the same as demonstrated on this page:
https://foundation.zurb.com/building-blocks/blocks/sticky-shrinknav.html

Instead, the nav bar is static (doesn't shrink or move) and some page components are above the navbar when scrolling, while others are beneath the navbar as i scroll.
My apologies if this is a noob question. I am new to Foundation.

---

EDIT: this is the app.js file contents:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'what-input';

// Foundation JS relies on a global varaible. In ES6, all imports are hoisted
// to the top of the file so if we used`import` to import Foundation,
// it would execute earlier than we have assigned the global variable.
// This is why we have to use CommonJS require() here since it doesn't
// have the hoisting behavior.
window.jQuery = $;
require('foundation-sites');

// If you want to pick and choose which modules to include, comment out the above and uncomment
// the line below
//import './lib/foundation-explicit-pieces';


$(document).foundation();
```

Comment: Please check the browser console if there are any errors. I see no foundation.js script reference.

Comment: This is not the browser console. Please do right click - inspect in your browser, switch to the console tab at the bottom and load the generated html page.

Comment: The console in both Firefox and Chrome is empty. I can't see where foundation.js is called either, but the page is responsive to resizing. I would assume this means that it is invoked somewhere, yes?

Comment: Generally no, the responsive comes from the CSS. Is there anything in the browser console when you scroll?

Comment: Also check if the body element gets the `sticky-shrinknav-wrapper` class when you scroll. If so, the only issues are the building block styles (see the variables in the scss file of it and things like the padding-top setting there).

Comment: Nothing in the console when i scroll.
There are no classes on the body tag before or after scrolling.

Comment: The config.yml file contains the path to the scss files, still can't find reference to the foundation.js file. The app.js file contains a require('foundation-sites'). The foundation-sites package in node-modules folder contains the foundation.js in the js subfolder

Comment: In general the JS should work if jQuery is loaded before this. See https://codepen.io/DanielRuf/pen/vvWEGE

Comment: Foundation is already loaded. Otherwise your bundle would not be so big. Check the generated bundle app.js if it contains your sticky code. Either change the order in the config or check the imports.

Comment: Adding the building block JS directly before / after `$(document).foundation();` should definitely work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185933/discussion-between-raptop-and-daniel-ruf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import the sticky-shrinknav component in your app.js (if you want to bundle it there). Otherwise you have to also include the generated bundle in your html file too.

But in general you need `const $ = require('jquery')` or `import $ from 'jquery'` as first line in the sticky-shrinknav file to load jQuery for it.